# How to round total only if BACS method checked. Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, rounding, checkout

I fonud function that rounds the total, but can't understand how to make it work only if BACS payment checked on checkout page.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total' );
function custom_calculated_total( $total ) {
  $total = round( $total, 1 );
return ceil($total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone will need, I found solution:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total' );

function custom_calculated_total( $total ) {
    if( WC()->session->get( 'chosen_payment_method' ) == 'bacs' )
    {
        $total = round( $total, 1 );
        $total = ceil( $total );
    }

    return $total;
}
```

[The woocommerce_calculated_total hook is documented here:](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_calculated_total/)